# Poor Performance Querying a 8 GB table with large columns and many rows

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a table with MySQL 4 and the table has a schema like this:

```
itemId int
essay longtext
dateCreated timestamp
creatorId int
```

Most of these essays are very large pastes from MS Word (think of multi-megabyte essays). I'm 
trying to query this table to merely determine who submitted an essay in a particular time frame. My first approach at this query was:

```
select creatorId from stories where dateCreated >= '2011-03-09 11:00:00';
```

This should only return about 10-20 results. Unfortunately, the query took over 10 minutes to complete (since the overall table size is 8 GB with 100,000 rows). The dateCreated column does have an index.

How can I improve the performance of this query?

Comment: 8 GB and 100,000 rows isn't so big, and it shouldn't take 10 minutes (you are not selecting the heavy column nor setting a condition on it). Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE stories;` and post the result? Looks like something is wrong with the index... Running `EXPLAIN SELECT ... ` would also be useful.

Comment: Does `dateCreated` allow NULLs ?

Comment: are you running this on a local desktop drive, or a disk array on a server?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at my table some more, I figured out the problem. My index was created incorrectly. I actually have other metadata in this table (such as dateLastUpdated and approved boolean). When I do a search like "where dateLastUpdated = x and approved = true and dateCreated >= y", it would benefit from a three column index on the fields. So it looks like I'll have to create a bunch of indices on this table. Hopefully I don't hurt insert performance by having too many indices. Sorry for bothering everyone.